# OLS regression when dependent variable's measurement is capped

Tags: least-squares, censoring

Let's say you have $y=a+xb$ but your $y$ variable is measured imperfectly such that the measurement never exceeds 99 but in reality it should.  We know it's a measurement issue.  Is the best technique to just filter out data where $y>98$ or is there a better way?

Comment: See our threads on [censored regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=censor*+regression).  Just filtering out those data will bias the results (as well as lose information).

Comment: Semiparametric models handle this in the simplest way perhaps.   Take a look at the proportional odds ordinal model which allows arbitrary data clumping and handles detection limits.